# How to use OWASP Java Encoder in JSP page?

Tags: jsp, owasp

I have been searching for hours but cannot find a clear example about how to do this. It would be very helpful for me if you can show me an example for protecting a page accepting input data and then display it on another page, thanks a lot.

Comment: Simple googling leads to https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project. If this doesn't solve your problem, please give a more specific question.

Comment: There is no example in this official link.

Answer (score 4):

https://owasp.github.io/owasp-java-encoder/encoder-jsp/index.html

```
<%@taglib prefix="e" uri="https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project" %>

<p>Dynamic data via EL: ${e:forHtml(param.value)}</p>
<p>Dynamic data via tag: <e:forHtml value="${param.value}" /></p>
```

Comment: What if I have something like `<p id="${param.value}">some text</p>` ?

Answer (score 1):

And if you aren't using EL:

```
<%@ page import="org.owasp.encoder.Encode" %>

<% String encodedString = Encode.forHtml(request.getParameter("untrustedParam")); %>
```