# Intellij will not recognize OWASP jsp tag library?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, intellij-idea, owasp

EDIT:   In response to comments, I have included the starting portion of the JSP file that I am trying to add the OWASP library to.    Multiple people have pointed out the statement:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="e" uri="https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project" %>
```

This statement is already in the JSP file. I have also added the required jars in the maven POM file dependencies.

Here are the opening lines from the JSP file.   As you can see, multiple taglib statements are already in the file and they are already used and they already work.    I am at a loss to explain why the OWASP taglib does not work.  Can anyone provide an example that works?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="asrs" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="e" uri="https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project" %>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >

<asrs:cssPath relativePath="find.css" />

<asrs:dojoConfig relativePath="lib/dojo/dojo.js" configValue="parseOnLoad: true"/>
<asrs:javascriptPath relativePath="lib/dojo/io/iframe.js"/>
<asrs:javascriptPath relativePath="lib/spring/Spring.js"/>
<asrs:javascriptPath relativePath="lib/spring/Spring-Dojo.js"/>
<asrs:javascriptPath relativePath="Metadata.js"/>
</head>

<body onunload="javascript: exitpop()" onresize="resize()">

<c:if test="${saved}">
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
top.close();
</script>
</c:if>

[code continues]
```

ORIGINAL POST:

I am trying to add the OWASP tag library to a Spring Boot project using embedded Tomcat.   The project documentation [here](https://owasp.github.io/owasp-java-encoder/encoder-jsp/index.html) and this other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36616462/how-to-use-owasp-java-encoder-in-jsp-page) indicates this should be correct:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="e" uri="https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project" %>
<p>Dynamic data via EL: ${e:forHtml(param.value)}</p>
<p>Dynamic data via tag: <e:forHtml value="${param.value}" /></p>
```

But I cannot get Intellij to recognize this tag library.   I've added both OWASP dependencies to the project but nothing seems to help:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.owasp.encoder</groupId>
    <artifactId>encoder</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.owasp.encoder</groupId>
    <artifactId>encoder-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Is this problem related to the OWASP libraries or to Spring Boot?

Comment: Have you put this at the top of the jsp page:
```
<%@ taglib prefix="e" uri="https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project" %>```

Comment: can you send the jsp file code

Comment: @Janil101 I have included a fragment of the JSP page in the revised post

Comment: I have edited My code with an example of Jsp and Owasp

Comment: There does not appear to be any resolution to this problem.    I've been directed by my management to abandon the use of this tag library and go back to using JSTL only for output escaping.    If OWASP ever wants to update their documentation I will be happy to look at this again.

Answer (score 0):

To use in a JSP with EL

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib prefix="e" uri="https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project" %>

<html>
<head>
<title>
<b><e:forHtml value="${param.title}" /></b>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
<b>${e:forHtml(param.data)}</b>
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have added this taglib statement in the JSP.   No change in the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this maven dependency if it helps:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
  <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
  <version>7.2.0</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
```

Then check if you have added the required dependency for JSP files in pom.xml for it to work in Spring Boot

Go through the official documentation [here](https://owasp.org/www-project-java-encoder/) you have added the right dependency for JSP Encode also go through the implementation documentation on GitHub provided by OWASP here is the [link](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-java-encoder)

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidating cache & restart in IntelliJ.

Comment: I have invalidated all caches and restarted with no change in the behavior.